# JQUERY onClick change 'top' attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a vertical scroller using jquery and I am having troubles with my code..

```
function scrolldown() {     
    var newtop = $('.scroll-content').css('top') + '250';   
    $('.scroll-content').css({top: newtop});
}
```

The css:

```
.scroll-content {position:absolute; top:0px}
```

No problems with CSS I can change values in firebug and works fine, but the code is the issue. I want it to add 250px to current value but it doesnt work and when using `.html(newtop)` i can see that the output for the "top" value is 0px250… any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('.scroll-content').css('top')
```

will return something like "123px", which is a string (due to the "px"). If you add "250", you have "123px250", which is not what you want...

Try this one instead:

```
var newtop = $('.scroll-content').position().top + 250;
$('.scroll-content').css('top', newtop + 'px');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the css string ('0px') into an int (0) so you can add 250, then add the 'px' again

```
function scrolldown() {
  var newtop = parseInt($('.scroll-content').css('top')) + 250;
  $('.scroll-content').css({top: newtop+'px'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the posted answers, you can use a `+=` shortcut via [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with no duration, like this:

```
$(".scroll-content").animate({ top: "+=250px" }, 0);​
```

This will make the change adding 250px instantly.  If you actually wanted it animated, just change that `0` to a `400` for example, to get a 400ms duration.

Comment: @cdutson - That's true of anything with a CSS `top` property...I'm not sure how that factors in, if you look at the question, the OP included the styling, it's a `position: absolute;` element.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding an integer to your top value not a string. see below:

```
var newtop = $('.scroll-content').css('top') + 250;
    $('.scroll-content').css({top: newtop}); }
```